# How to get a Blend Tree Object from Animator in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an Animator object. And there is a blend tree in one of its states (named "normal_state"). I want to gain this BlendTree object by code. How to do?

```
private BlendTree blendtree;
public Animator ani;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //blendtree=???
}
```

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1401279/how-can-i-access-blend-tree-in-animator-controller.html

Comment: Oh, that's it. Each state has a motion. And blendtree inherits from motion. We just need to cast state.motion to blendtree.